# Is there an OS-imposed speed limit on how much data can Node.js take in in a socket(s)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, hosting, file-transfer

I've been looking at [Generic Route Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation). It made me wonder:

What is the speed limit in terms of data intake through a Node.js server?

Let's say I need 100Gb transferred in a jiffy, on a private datacenter network. Is it the OS that bottlenecks at that point or what?